# How do actions work in Liferay?

Tags: jsp, liferay, action, portlet

I've looked for this question, but couldn't find it.

I don't know for you, but I don't understand a single bit of the Liferay Tutorial. It's too big and non-explanatory. This led me into a big misunderstanding on how Actions work in Liferay and a pair of troublesome tests.

---

Given this introduction, let's be quick: **how do Liferay actions work?**

- I know we have ActionRequests and ActionResponses at methods, but how do I trigger an ActionRequest on these? Do I need renderURL tags for it? Can you give an example?
- Now that after the previous question I should be able to call a method in my Portlet class controller... how do I send the info to the client? I guess it's using the ActionResponse, but how do I handle this?

Thank you!

edit:

I gave a try to the first answer, yet I tried something very similar before. It's not working, but I'm getting this error on the console; I don't really know if this might be a problem:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://www.google.es/?gfe_rd=ssl&ei=8Sc8V5OkBYGFaLiHksgO does not
>   permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: Are you trying to use Liferay even though you don't understand the tutorial? Isn't that kind of a bad premise?

Comment: Just test purposes! Nothing that will go to production, clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your my_action.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

Hello : <b> <%=request.getAttribute("user-test") %></b>

<portlet:defineObjects />
//The name here is used to call the process action method you define for your action
<portlet:actionURL name="myAction" var="myActionUrl"></portlet:actionURL>



<aui:form action="${myActionUrl}">
    <aui:input name="inputField"></aui:input>
    <aui:button-row>
        <aui:button type="cancel" />
        <aui:button type="submit" value="save" />
    </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>
```

and than in the portlet class

```
public class CustomMVCPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    public void myAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException,     PortletException, PortalException, SystemException{
       //get value inserted in form 
        String userName = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "inputField", StringPool.BLANK);
       //her you send back your data to use in the jsp
        actionRequest.setAttribute("user-test", userName);
    }
```

Mapping from action to method is done using the name in the actionRequest.setAttribute nd the name of the method in the class that extends MVCPortlet and is defined using the tags `<portlet-class>fully.qulified.name</portlet-class>` in `WEB-INF/portlet.xml`  if no method is found a PortletException is thrown

Comment: Thank you! But it's not working, I just see a green message saying "Your request has been succesful"; the "user" variable never gets shown.

Comment: Sorry..my bad.Form must be done using aui-tags, this way the variable gets readed in the portlet class. Also changed variable user in case you have used `<portlet:defineObjects />` this may cause to read the liferay user you are using

Comment: It's still not working... check this screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/QONtIKH.png . I used exactly your code, just importing the aui tag:  <%@ taglib prefix="aui" uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" %>

Comment: Try adding this `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>` in your `liferay-portlet.xml`

Comment: Finally found put whats wrong...the `${user-test}` of EL somehow doesn't read the requestAttribute set in portlet, replaced it with `<%=request.getAttribute("user-test") %>` and now it looks fine...

Comment: Now it works! It was definitely what you wrote in your last comment. Thank you :) ! edit: You should edit your main answer so other people can see the actual resolution.